# Remove outer/border contours from plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

When ploting a 3D data set with `matplotlib.pyplot.contourf`, the outer or border contours, near the unsampled regions, are colored as in the full contour levels.

How can I remove those outer contours and obtain a plot similar to `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh`?

```
plt.subplot(1,2, 1)
plt.contourf(x,y,zt,levels=levels)
plt.title("contourf")

plt.subplot(1,2, 2)
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,zt)
plt.title("pcolormesh")
```

[image]

Comment: The contour necessarily interpolates the values. Just as with isolines on a weather map or in catography, you cannot jump from one high value to a low value without traversing those in between.

Comment: Sure, that is what happens with contourf. But I am wondering if there is some trick... Maybe plotting twice, with a thicker border?

Comment: I see. In this specific case that might work since e.g. you do not have green in the inner part. So you may plot a `contour` (without f) plot at the value of green color with a thick line colored in blue. That might hide all undesired edge parts.